# How to let an argument be empty without breaking if?

Tags: biblatex

I was refactoring a biblatex-style to work with changes recently introduced to biber. So I had this code:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartprefixi}{}{\namepartsuffix}}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last-init}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefixi}{\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-last-init}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
}%
```

But this code always gives me the errors "extra \or" (for both \or s) and "extra \fi". When debugging, I figured out, that filling in just anything into the `{}` in the first branch makes the code work. But I need to have an empty argument there. Why does it make a difference if the argument is empty or not for the if structure? And, even more important: how do I submit an empty argument in there?

Comment: I really don't understand the details, but I've found that often, `\relax` can satisfy your need.  It is not "nothing", but it performs "nothing" when executed.

Comment: It does nothing *successfully* :-).

Comment: It's hard to help you if you don't give us code to reproduce your problem. Like Steven, I would have thought that adding `\relax` after `\value{uniquename}` would probably fix the problem but I can't test this from what you have posted. Can you please expand your code snippet to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: You can use the macros \empty and \@empty.  It has been my experience that {} gets translated as \@empty, so break out the \makeatletter ... \makeatother.

Comment: great, using \relax works. Seems that the – not too well documented – changes in biblatex recently made the macros not accepting {} as empty arguments anymore…. If you're posting this as an answer again, I'll accept it as the correct solution :)

Comment: `\ifcase\value{uniquename}%` should work (as it does in the standard definition of `labelname`). Note that in version 3.3 of `biblatex` `name:first-last` should rather be `name:given-family`. Also `name:first-last-init` is non-standard so we would have to see that as well (and indeed another problem could come from there if the tests for emptiness are still the old ones). Plus, I'm not sure what you say about leaving the branch with an empty group - that would mean you get no name in some situations? Please consider providing a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough context to run the code but you have

```
\ifcase\value{uniquename}%
```

here `\ifcase` requires a `<number>`, and assuming the standard latex definition of `\value` then `\value{uniquename}` will be a number just if `uniquename` is a latex counter, that is, if `\c@uniquename` is defined to be a count register.

If `\c@uniqename` isn't defined then `\value` will define it `\let` to `\relax`.  You don't say what non-error behaviour you want, but for example you could make it act as -1, in which case none of the `\ifcase` branches will be executed.

```
\ifcase\expandafter\ifx\csname c@uniquename\endcsname\relax-1 \else\value{uniquename}\fi
```

Comment: actually looking at your question again perhaps that isn't the `\if..` you are asking about, but it's the only one in the posted code, hard to be sure. If the question is updates I'll revisit this.

Comment: I'd bet on the conditionals in `name:first-last-init`. With the `biblatex` changes in 3.3 the type of the arguments changed, I guess that could confuse the `\if...` commands there.